# How to format integer padded with both sign and zeros?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I need to format time with leading sign and hour (think timezone offset) in Python3:

```
>>> hour = 2
>>> print("T%02d" % hour)
T02
>>> print("T%+02d" % hour)
T+2
```

Expected result is `T+02`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The field includes the `+` character, which needs to be accounted for in the width. You want your field to be *3* characters wide:

```
print("T%+03d" % hour)
```

Demo:

```
>>> hour = 2
>>> print("T%+03d" % hour)
T+02
```